# Cannot convert NUMBER to SEQUENCE in Changefeed on SUM operation in RethinkDB

Tags: sum, rethinkdb

I am getting an error when listening on changes event while doing a SUM query, without the changes() method it works fine

What I expect this code to do is SUM each 'length' attribute on this table that matches the filter, and when there is a new item inserted in this table, SUM again and notify me.

```
r.db('buckets')
.table("fs_files")
.filter({metadata: data})
.sum('length')
.changes()
.run(req._rdbConn, function(err, cursor) {
    ... notify me using socket.io (not important here)
});
```

What I get is

```
name: 'ReqlQueryLogicError',
msg: 'Cannot convert NUMBER to SEQUENCE',
frames: [],
message: 'Cannot convert NUMBER to SEQUENCE in
```

Does anyone have a solution for this? Or is my logic wrong as the error message says?

Answer (score 1):

This will be possible only in version 2.4 as Daniel said [here](https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/1118).

Just for now you can try to use `fold`:

```
r.db("buckets").table("fs_files").filter({metadata: data})('length')("num").changes({"includeInitial": true}).fold(0, function(acc, change) {
        return acc.add(change("new_val").sub(change("old_val").default(0)))
    }, {emit: function(prev, change, acc) {
        return [acc]
    }
    }).run(con, function(err, cursor) {
        if(!cursor)
            return;
        cursor.each(function(err, row) {
            // here we go
        })
    });
```